Single axis line for grouped axes labels in D3
I'm trying to implement a heat map in D3+reactjs with grouped/multi-level axes displayed in opposite sides. Year labels on top x-axis, day labels on bottom x-axis and months on y-axis scale.
Also separate the years with some line separators
I did try this -
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const Heatmap = () => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    const margin = { top: 40, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 80 };
    const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue"];
    const months = [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ];
    const data = [
      { year: 2021, month: "Jan", day: 1, value: 58 },
      { year: 2021, month: "Feb", day: 2, value: 45 },
      { year: 2022, month: "Jan", day: 1, value: 53 },
      { year: 2022, month: "Feb", day: 3, value: 70 },
      { year: 2023, month: "Jan", day: 1, value: 52 },
      { year: 2023, month: "Feb", day: 1, value: 65 },
      { year: 2024, month: "Jan", day: 2, value: 48 },
      { year: 2024, month: "Feb", day: 2, value: 46 },
    ];
    const yearScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.year))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.1);

    const dayScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(days)
      .range([0, yearScale.bandwidth()])
      .padding(0.1);

    const yScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(months)
      .range([height, 0])
      .padding(0.1);

    const g = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    g.append("g").attr("class", "year-axis").call(d3.axisTop(yearScale));

    g.selectAll(".day-axis")
      .data(data.map((d) => d.year))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "day-axis")
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${yearScale(d)}, ${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(dayScale));

    g.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    const nestedData = data.reduce((acc, d) => {
      acc[d.year] = (acc[d.year] || []).concat(d);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    g.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object.entries(nestedData))
      .enter()
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data((d) => d[1])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d) => yearScale(d.year) + dayScale(days[d.day - 1]))
      .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.month))
      .attr("width", dayScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
      .style("fill", (d) => getColor(d.value));

    function getColor(value) {
      const colorScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range(["#fff", "#f00"]);
      return colorScale(value);
    }
  }, []);

  return <svg ref={svgRef} width={1500} height={400} />;
};

export default Heatmap;


But I'm getting separate day axis generated for each year. Output looks like - Heatmap
